# Verify Minimum of a certain function

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Consider $\frac{1}{2} \leq a,b \leq 1$ and an arbitrary but fixed $\varepsilon$ between $0$ and 1

I would like to verify that the function

$$a + b - \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 - 2ab + \frac{4ab}{(1+\varepsilon)^2}}$$

is minimized for $a = b = \frac{1}{2}$.

I tried the following in Mathematica to verify this but this does not really help. Does anyone know how to verify this bound with Mathematica?

```
    minimize a+b- sqrt(a^2+b^2 - 2ab + (4ab)/(1+x)^2) in 1/2 <= a <= 1, 1/2 <= b <= 1, 0 <= x <= 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using correct Mathematica syntax you'll get

```
min = Minimize[{a + b - Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b + (4 a b)/(1 + x)^2], 1/2 <= a <= 1, 1/2 <= b <= 1, 0 < x < 1}, {a, b}];
Simplify[min,0<x<1]

(*{x/(1 + x), {a -> 1/2, b -> 1/2}}*)
```